# How to take an image from My SQL database and add it to a .html page

Tags: php, html, image

I have some images in a database which I would like to add to a html page
This is my current code

```
<div class = "gridrow">
    <?php
        foreach (range(1, 4) as $value) {
        $result = $conn->query("select * from products where product_ID = '".$value."'");
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        $name_p1 = $row['product'];
        $price_p1 = $row['price'];
        $image = "<img src='{$row['image']}'>";
        echo "<div class = 'productwindow' >";
            echo "<div class = 'productimage'><".$image."></div>";
            echo "<div class = 'productvar'><p>".$name_p1."</p></div>";
            echo "<div class = 'productvar'><p>$".$price_p1."</p></div>";
        echo "</div>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

[This is what the page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqJof.png)

[These are the errors I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woeye.png)

How can I make these images show correctly?

Comment: For starters, you'll need to run a PHP script on a `.php` page rather than a `.html` page (unless you're explicitly enabling that functionality in `.html` through Apache2's `@mime.conf`)...

Comment: First fix your SQL injection.  Second, you probably shouldn't be storing images in the database, its not what database are good at.  If you insist on doing so, use `<img src="data:image/png;base64, ' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing image *data* in the database, while the `img` `src` tag wants image *URLs*, that's why it's getting confused and you're getting errors.

The quick way around it is to convert the image data to `base64` and pipe it in the `src` tag like so:

```
$image = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'">';
```

This is at best a hack, and [not a great idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) for a host of reasons, it also assumes all your images are PNG.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems like a good solution for what I am doing but it will be a few days before I can test it out

Comment: Did you test it out?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it has been a while since I logged in. This worked perfectly, thanks